# JavaScript String replace - How do you use matched variables in the replacement string?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How do you use the matched variables in the pattern in the replacement string?

```
var regexp = new RegExp('needle', 'ig');
str.replace(regexp, '<span class="marked">//1</span>')
```

Comment: I think you should have a read of this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @Peter Kelly: I'm not sure this is valid - his example does not reference *parsing* HTML, but instead deals with adding HTML tags around a string.  Which is a perfectly valid use for a Regex.

Comment: Where did you see that you could use `//1`? Read the documentation on the replace string more closely, especially the part about the special `$` variables.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try

```
var regexp = new RegExp(something, 'ig');
str.replace(regexp, '<span class="marked">$&</span>')
```

References:

- [A table specifying the format of different tokens to be used into the replacement string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)
- [An example on how to switch two words into a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example.3a_Switching_words_in_a_string)

Comment: it works.. but why $& ? what if you got some groups in the pattern.. $1 etc doesnt seem to work

Comment: Interesting.  I actually didn't know about the `$&`, `$'` and $` replacements.

Comment: @claekk: $& represent the matched string, $n represent the nth group matched. If you don't use group matching should be preferable ($1 should work too, though). See the reference I added

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to use backreferences in JavaScript is via `$1`...`$9`.

To make your example work:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(something, 'ig');
var result = str.replace(regexp, '<span class="marked">$1</span>');
```

More information is available here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html#replace

Comment: To use the numeric backreferences, you'll need to wrap your regex in parentheses: `/(needle)/`.  Otherwise, use `$&` that Eineki shows.