# Angular 2 pipe replace with source value

Tags: javascript, angular

I wrote the following pipe to highlight matching:

```
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'highlight' })
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: any, filter: string): any[] {
    let highlightedValues = [];

    values.forEach(function(entry) {
      let result = filter ? HighlightPipe.doHighlight(entry, filter) : entry;
      filter ? highlightedValues.push(result) : highlightedValues.push(entry);
    });

    return highlightedValues;
  }

  private static doHighlight(entry:any, filter:string):any {
    return {
      title: entry.title.replace(new RegExp(filter, 'gi'), `<span class="highlight">${filter}</span>`),
      content: entry.content.replace(new RegExp(filter, 'gi'), `<span class="highlight">${filter}</span>`)
    };
  }
}
```

The pipe works fine and hihlights matches. The problem occurs, when I search for an upper case string. The upper case string replaces the source text **what is not wanted behaviour**.

For example: I search for `Array` string and the source string (`array`) gets replaced with `Array` string. How can I make pipe return `array` and not `Array`?

P.S. `highlightedValues` is there, because the pipe takes output from another pipe.

Comment: You could use the matched string in the output, rather than the actual `filter` value.

Comment: could you please show some example?

Comment: Just replace `${filter}` (TypeScript interpolation of the specific value) with `$&` (regex interpolation of the match). Read up on it in e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript String replace - How do you use matched variables in the replacement string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993492/javascript-string-replace-how-do-you-use-matched-variables-in-the-replacement)

Comment: @jonrsharpe it worked for me. You can post the answer and I accept it.

Comment: Then accept the duplicate suggestion, which already has that answer; this isn't specific to TypeScript or Angular 2.